# Tailwind and Vite warnings: "didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime"

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm using the following combination of technologies:

- **SvelteKit** (1.5.0, using TypeScript), with **Vite** (4.0.0) as the build tool that comes with SvelteKit)
- Svelte's **`adapter-static`** (2.0.1) for publishing to GitHub Pages
- **TailwindCSS** with the Typography plugin
- The **Inter** font families via `import '../inter.css';` in `+layout.svelte`

When running `npm run build` I get a bunch of these warnings (newlines for readability:

```
/img/logo.png referenced in D:/git/my-org/my-repo/src/app.css
  didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime
```

```
/fonts/Inter-Thin.woff2?v=3.19 referenced in D:/git/my-org/my-repo/src/inter.css
  didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime
```

For me personally, the build output actually *works*, and includes all said resources. Also if I delete the output folder and generate a completely fresh build. I'm experiencing no problem or error. But the output feels like warnings to me, and "*warnings are errors from the future*"!

So, my question is: **What does this message above *mean*, and should I treat it as a warning and change something?**

### How to reproduce (*with* Svelte)

Here's one way to reproduce said warning:

1. `npm create svelte@latest my-app`, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/creating-a-project, I chose "Skeleton Project" with TypeScript and Prettier
2. Follow https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit in short:

   - `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`
   - `npx tailwindcss init tailwind.config.cjs -p`
   - the `vitePreprocess` was already in my `svelte.config.ts`
   - `content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}']` in `tailwind.config.js`
   - add `@tailwind` directives to a new `app.css` file and `import` it in a fresh `+layout.svelte` file
3. Add `<div class="bg-[url('/favicon.png')]">Repro.</div>` to `+page.svelte`
4. Run `npm run build`

In short, it seems to be triggered by [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) referencing other files? (At this point I'm not sure if Svelte is strictly needed to reproduce the issue, perhaps just Tailwind+Vite is enough?)

### How to reproduce (*without* Svelte)

It can also be done without Svelte, just Tailwind in a Vite project:

1. Follow https://vitejs.dev/guide/ (`npm create vite@latest`), pick "Vanilla"
2. Follow https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite but skip the Vite creation step (already done) and add the `@tailwind` directives to `style.css` from the template
3. Add `class="bg-[url('vite.svg')]"` to the `<body>` tag

The same warning occurs here too.

---

Footnote: I had [added my repro as a comment to Vite GitHub issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10766#issuecomment-1455209749) which has since been [marked as resolved by a PR](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/12873).

Comment: Thank you! I was also thinking on making this exact question out of annoyance so you saved me on doing it :-D. In the mean while, I investigated a bit and you can clear them off if you follow the expected Vite's path for static files. If you do this, however, it won't find the files when you run the compiled project. It suggests to me that Vite's compilation is leaving these aside for the SvelteKit's adapters to resolve the way that suits the best to them. IMHO, this is should be better clarified and handled by the team but, like you said, it doesn't make the project less functional.

Comment: Cheers! Your comment makes me feel like I should maybe open up a GitHub issue about it, but it's very hard to tell which project I should open it at.

Comment: Since Vite is merely the compiler here, I suggest the ticket to be raised on the SvelteKit project since, at the end of the day, it is SvelteKit the one that commands Vite into compiling what it is expected.

Comment: At first glance that made sense to me too. But trying to prepare a reproducible scenario for such an issue, I found that it probably has nothing to do with Svelte, and is an Vite+Tailwind issue. - I'll add the initial repro to the question in a second, but would have to create a Tailwind+Vite project with no Svelte to be sure of things.

Comment: Indeed, vanilla Vite with Tailwind also has this situation. Added it to the question.

Comment: Oh, wow! You blew my mind there. I would have swear it was an SvelteKit issue. This makes me even more curious about it. Thank you!

Comment: Found [this related GitHub issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10766#issuecomment-1455209749) from past November, thinking that should pop up with a solution.

Comment: Nice one! You went way further than I did. Let's see if somebody provides some solution. Cheers!

Comment: I was browsing SO and I stumbled upon [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75654885/sveltekit-use-local-assets-inside-of-global-css-file). I immediately thought on our discussion here so I had to try it. Guess what... it totally works! It not only keeps the log quiet but it also bundles the correct files! Instead of `$lib` tho, I added `$fonts: resolve('./static/fonts')` into my `vite.config.ts` and then I used `$fonts` inside the CSS file. I'm totally baffled but at least there is a workaround (although it looks like the solution to tell Vite where the files are).

Comment: Thanks for sharing @carlosV2!  I'll give that a try as well soon.

Comment: @carlosV2 Could you please show exactly how you add `$font: resolve()` into the `vite.config.ts` file? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: @carlosV2 Probably this: `export default defineConfig({ plugins: [sveltekit()], resolve: { alias: { $fonts: "./static/fonts" } } });` (works for me, thanks for the tip)

Comment: Hi @NicolasLeThierryd'Ennequin, yes, that's the way. I think I'm going to add this as an answer to this question so future people has a simpler solution.

Answer (score 11):

It seems like the potential solution is to declare your static paths in your `vite.config.ts` file. For example:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';

const config: UserConfig = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      $fonts: resolve('./static/fonts')
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

Of course, this is still applicable to other [Vite configurations](https://vitejs.dev/config/) (like for javascript).

Once you have this alias set, you can use it like this in your `app.css`:

```css
@font-face {
  src: url('$fonts/<your font file here>') format('woff2');
  /* Any other font directive */
}
```

Please, note that I'm merely providing this answer to try and help anyone. Credit, however, should go to @H.B. in this other [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75654885/use-local-assets-inside-of-global-css-file).

Comment: Interesting! Will try this solution some time later. Curious to see if it also can fix the `class="bg-[url('vite.svg')]"` variant. Either way: thanks for sharing!

Comment: Alas, couldn't get it to work in a way that works for both `npm run dev` and for `npm run build`.

Comment: I'm curious on knowing how you want this to work. I've tried with `class="bg-[url('$static/vite.svg')]"` and it work for both `npm run dev` and `npm run build`. The only change I had to make was to tell Vite's development server to [allow serving from the root](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-fs-allow) of the project (probably it can be further constrained).

Comment: Same problem as @Jeroen: while this solution solves the problem for build, the paths are broken in dev server mode. For instance, instead of the expected "/fonts/" path, the requested path is "/@fs/fonts/". Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: @Jeroen To solve the dev/build problem, you may want to take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75847037/494979

Comment: @NicolasLeThierryd'Ennequin good stuff! Haven't tried it yet but it looks like a good solution. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

For those who are using *Vite with vanilla JS and tailwind*. This part of https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory worked for me.

> Note that:
>
> You should always reference public assets using root absolute path -
> for example, public/icon.png should be referenced in source code as
> /icon.png.

Writing

`class="bg-[url('/wood-bg.jpg')"`

succeeds but

`class="bg-[url('./wood-bg.jpg')"`

gives "didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome, this fixed my build paths (I'm using Vite v4.3.3)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Vue 3, Vite, and Quasar. The below worked for me in the .vue file. It took me a lot of time to crack this.

Inside HTML the below worked.

```
<q-header elevated style="background-image: url('assets/header_altcolor.png')">
```

I had the problem inside CSS and the below finally worked for me in CSS.

```
.pageLayout {
  background-image: url('/assets/landingpage_bg.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

The only difference was a slash in the front when we use it in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

For those using the Laravel/Inertia/Vue stack, the problem seems to be Laravel's use of an alias from the *storage* directory to the *public* directory. So, similar to answers above, replace the alias with an absolute url.

replace:

```
url('/storage/images/homeBg_2xl.jpg')
```

with:

```
url('../../storage/app/public/images/homeBg_2xl.jpg')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue when setting the `background-image` of a SvelteKit component. This is what I did to get the error in production:

```
.selector {
  background-image: url("src/assets/images/name-of-image.jpg");
}
```

I found out that omitting the `/` at the beginning of the file path caused the error in production. So I simply added the `/` at the beginning of the file path and the images now appear in production:

```
.selector {
  background-image: url("/src/assets/images/name-of-image.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the other approach is to convert your image to base64, then use it in your CSS file.

```
background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,<base64code>");
```

Answer (score 0):

**I was also facing the same problem but I solved this**

> updating my vite.config.ts

[Config : vite.config.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3n6n.jpg)

[Css : adding in css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLFX8.jpg)