# Use local assets inside of global CSS file?

Tags: sveltekit

If I have a global CSS file which defines some basic colors and fonts and all that, and include it in my top-level layout file with a simple `import "$lib/assets/app.css"`, then how can I reference local fonts and images from within that css file, which are also in the `/lib/assets` folder? Currently it seems I have to put those files into `/static`, but that results in warnings when creating a build, and more importantly, they get cached in the browser for only 4 hours.

As an example, I have something like this in my `$lib/assets/app.css` file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Custom";
  src: url("/fonts/Bitter-Regular.ttf");
  font-display: swap;
}
```

That works fine when that font is placed in the `/static` folder but I'd rather have it placed in `$lib/assets` because presumably that would mean it becomes part of the immutable build and gets cached way way longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `$lib` in your CSS:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Custom";
  src: url("$lib/assets/fonts/Bitter-Regular.ttf");
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Comment: Oh damn, that easy? Not sure why I didn't try that, I just assumed it was a special syntax that was only available on Svelte / JS files. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: That should just be a [Vite feature](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias) which in turn is powered by `@rollup/plugin-alias`. (The `$lib` alias is something SvelteKit adds, as far as I know.)

Comment: This is awesome, by far the best solution possible :)